# Windows Web Platform Installer vs Manual Install?

Tags: webserver, windows-server-2008-r2, web-platform-installer

I am going to be moving all my websites to a Windows Web Server 2008 R2 machine. I have installed it in a virtual machine to test that my websites work with it.

I have noticied that there is a program called Web Platform Installer. I have used it to install a few sites but I was just thinking is it a security risk using this? Would it be better for me to manually install the sites (WordPress, Umbraco, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We push that out to all our customers just for ease of deployment, and I have not seen any security issues with it, however, I would question its reliability as it fails about 10% of the time (to install whatever I have selected). Having said that, when it does work, its a fairly good tool, as it will install any prerequisites that you may not have been aware of (like SMO, or if you try to install Wordpress without MySQL), and will also keep you up-to-date on newer version of software that you have installed.

Comment: I should have added that MS recently released a command-line tool for WebPI also, so you could automate deployment via WebPI if you so desired.